import local module in Python
My project structure looks like:
my_project/
├── common_lib/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── file1.py
│   └── file2.py
└── module1/
    ├── src/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── script1.py
    │   └── script2.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main.py

And I am trying to import functions from file1.py and file2.py in main.py and in script1.py as:
main.py:
from common_lib.file1 import func1

script1.py:
from common_lib.file2 import func2

I am trying to import functions from common_lib to script1.py, and main.py.
I have added common_lib and module1 in windows env variable (absolute paths under python path). Along with VSCode's project setting.json as well. when I run python main.py in powershell (with current dir as module1) I am getting error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common_lib'

UPDATE:
I have installed common_lib by including setup.py as:
pip install -e <path_to_common_lib\common_lib>

Which was successful, but still when I try to import function like below, I am getting ModuleNotFoundError:
from common_lib.file1 import func1


This question is similar to: Python error "ImportError: No module named". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Entirely different @Luuk. I am trying to run on Windows (created on Windows), and not trying on linux/unix. So for sure there are no hidden edit in init.py files. I assume in your suggested link, the scripts were created in Windows but moved to unix. Thanks

Please: "make it clear how it’s different....."  Sharing a [mre] (with code) might be useful.

The answer is in chapter "6.1.2. The Module Search Path" of this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

how you do import please share your code

Please clarify which script you are running, what the current working directory is when you invoke it, whether you are running system Python.exe or a venv Python.exe and whether or not you installed the common lib using the pip install -e 'path/to/module option.

I have added common_lib and module1 in windows env variable Please show exactly how you did this, including the env variable name and exact value.

Hi @nigh_anxiety, I have edited my question. I am running system python.exe. I am trying to run main.py from module1 as working dir in Powershell. I have not installed "pip install -e common_lib". Thanks.
